# How to change column name on export?

Tags: jquery, datatables

I would like to change the name of a column in the resulting CSV file when exporting. Right now the table and CSV file display "Severity" and I would like to change the name to "Severe" in the CSV.

Is there any way to do this?

Right now, my code looks like this:

```
opentable = $("#open").dataTable({
    dom: "Bfrtip",
    "data": openData,
    "columns": [{
        data: "severity", render: function (data, type, row) {
            if (type === 'export') {
                return data;
            } else {
                return '';
            }
        }
    }],
    "paging": true,
    "searching": true,
    buttons : [{
        extend: 'csv',
        exportOptions: {
            columns: [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], orthogonal: 'export'
        }
    }]
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [csv option](https://datatables.net/reference/button/csv):

> customize: Function that can be used to modify the contents of the exported data. The function takes two parameters, the data as configured by the button and the button's configuration object. The value that the function returns is the value that will be used for the export.
>
> This can be particularly useful if you wish to add a company header or footer, description data or any other information to the exported data.

Using this option you can change for the first exported row the the column name  "Severity"  to "Severe":

```
customize: function (csv) {
    var csvRows = csv.split('\n');
    csvRows[0] = csvRows[0].replace('"Severity"', '"Severe"')
    return csvRows.join('\n');
}
```

```js
var openData = [
    {
        "name": "Tiger Nixon",
        "position": "System Architect",
        "salary": "$320,800",
        "start_date": "2011\/04\/25",
        "office": "Edinburgh",
        "severity": "5421"
    },
    {
        "name": "Donna Snider",
        "position": "Customer Support",
        "salary": "$112,000",
        "start_date": "2011\/01\/25",
        "office": "New York",
        "severity": "4226"
    }
];

var opentable = $("#open").dataTable({
    dom: "Bfrtip",
    "data": openData,
    "columns": [
        {data: 'name'},
        {data: 'position'},
        {data: 'office'},
        {data: 'salary'},
        {data: 'start_date'},
        {
            data: "severity",
            render: function (data, type, row) {
                if (type === 'export') {
                    return data;
                } else {
                    return '';
                }
            }
        }],
    "paging": true,
    "searching": true,
    buttons: [{
        extend: 'csv',
        exportOptions: {
            columns: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
            orthogonal: 'export'
        },
        filename: 'file',
        fieldSeparator: ';',
        customize: function (csv) {
            var csvRows = csv.split('\n');
            csvRows[0] = csvRows[0].replace('"Severity"', '"Severe"')
            return csvRows.join('\n');
        }
    }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.3.1/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css">
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.3.1/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.3.1/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>


<table id="open">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Position</th>
        <th>Office</th>
        <th>Salary</th>
        <th>Start date</th>
        <th>Severity</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

Comment: This is great! I completely missed this option in the documentation. Thanks for your help.

Comment: How could you loop through all the values in a column to edit them?